# mysql date syntax issue

Tags: java, mysql, date

I'm new to MySql database and currently facing an issue with date format. I have tried few solutions from the internet but nothing worked. Hence I'm posting the question here.

I have a GUI where I'm providing the date as input, which is in "mm/dd/yyyy" format.

This is my code which contains the query:

```
  public boolean fetchAPReportDomino(Date edDate, APReport apReport ){
    Statement stmt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    SimpleDateFormat sd= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sd1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String tempDate=sd.format(edDate);
    if(getConnection()!=null){

            try {
                stmt= getConnection().createStatement();

               String query="SELECT * FROM AP_Report where Edition Date = " + tempDate;
               rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
               while (rs.next()) {
                   apReport.setRoomHumidity(rs.getInt("Room Humidity"));
                   apReport.setRoomTemperature(rs.getInt("Room Temperature"));
               }
               rs.close();
               stmt.close();

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DataService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                return false;
            }
    }
    return true;
}
```

from the MySql workbench, I have tried changing the date field to "DATE", "TIMESTAMP", "DATETIME" datatypes. But nothing has helped.

Below is the error which Im seeing when I execute the code:

```
SEVERE: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Date = 02/14/2015' at line 1
```

Posting screenshot of table structure below:

```
http://prntscr.com/6qz5my
```

Comment: Learn about prepared statements, and pass the Date as a parameter of type java.sql.Date. Not by concatenating a String: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Also, your date field on database can't be `Edition Date` (with space) unless it was created with backticks so you have to use it!

Comment: Can you provide us the table structure ?

Comment: pasting a screent of table structure:

http://prntscr.com/6qz5my

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** do not ever create database fields like it was simple names with spaces (e.g. `Edition Date`) in between the words this is a **very bad practice** and it makes the use of it even worse while programming.
This is the image you added in the comments:
[image]

I strongly recommend you to change that to something like `edition_date`. the database fields do not need to be pretty just understandable.

**Second** since you created the fields like that you have to use backtics `` ` `` in all queries you run on the database with that fields otherwise the sql parser does not know how to recognize a field that has a name like `Edition Date`

The error you are seeing:

```
...server version for the right syntax to use near 'Date = 02/14/2015' at line 1
```

States exactly what I said about the fields names it show you `'Date = 02/14/2015'` because the sql parser think that the `Edition` word is a command or an operator so the rest it can't recognize.

The right way to use it on the query you create is like this:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM AP_Report where `Edition Date` = " + tempDate;
```

See the backticks?

But this way is still wrong because your query is a string without a Prepared Statement which means that you have to wrap your value `tempDate` with single quote so the right way is:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM AP_Report where `Edition Date` = '" + tempDate + "'";
```

But it still have a problem, the default mysql date format for compare as string is `yyyy-MM-dd` see it here: [Date Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76827/1) (the second query gets nothing because of the format)

On your code you are formating the date that is to be used on the query with this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sd= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat sd1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String tempDate=sd.format(edDate);
```

You are using `sd` on your query when you should use `sd1` so

```
String tempDate=sd1.format(edDate);
```

After that you can use the query as:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM AP_Report where `Edition Date` = '" + tempDate + "'";
```

**Note:** I don't really remember if you have to use the backticks when retrieving the value here `apReport.setRoomHumidity(rs.getInt("Room Humidity"));` so you should test as `` apReport.setRoomHumidity(rs.getInt("`Room Humidity`")); `` if the first way does not work.

And for the sake of knowledge you should consider in use prepared statement which in your code would be something like:

```
//...

String query="SELECT * FROM AP_Report where `Edition Date` = ?"
PreparedStatement pstmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(query);

//note that depending on your date type you will need just one 
//of the lines below

//if your edDate is a java.util.Date use as:
pstmt.setDate(new java.sql.Date(edDate.getTime()));
//if it is already a java.sql.Date
pstmt.setDate(edDate);

rs = pstmt.executeQuery(query);

//...
```

Hope it clears things out to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is the blank spaces in your column name , 
try something like `Edition Date` (or double quotes)

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that you need quotes around the date in the query string. Using the quotes as below and df1 should work.

```
String query="SELECT * FROM AP_Report where Edition Date = '" + tempDate + "'";
```

I also recommend looking into PreparedStatement when substituting variables into your query.

Comment: This answer is wrong as the error specifics says about the field `Date` which he is trying to query it should be `\`Edition Date\`` with backtics

Answer (score -1):

Date parameter must be in '' like a string data:

String query="SELECT * FROM AP_Report where Edition Date = '" + tempDate + "'";

Comment: This answer is wrong as the error specifics says about the field `Date` which he is trying to query it should be `\`Edition Date\`` with backtics